# Interval extensionality?

Tags: agda, cubical-type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

[I asked the following question on the CS SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/100175/26856):

> For example, in the proof of lemma 6.4.1 in the HoTT book, a function
>   inductively defined over a function is simply applied on paths `loop`
>   and `refl`, and then a path between `loop` and `refl` is used
>   (presumably by congruence via `f`) to construct a path between `f loop` and `f refl`:
>
> > Suppose that `loop = refl base`. [...] with `x : A` and `p : x = x`, there is a function `f : S1 → A` defined by `f(base) :≡ x` and
> >     `f(loop) := p`, we have
> >
> > ```
> > p = f(loop) = f(refl base) = refl x.
> > ```
>
> But in a cubical setting, things are not so clear-cut. `f(loop)` is
>   not well-typed, only `f(loop i)` is, for some `i : I`. But then that
>   above proof becomes
>
> ```
> p = <i> f (loop i) = <i> f (refl base i) = refl x
> ```
>
> but doesn't that need some kind of "interval extensionality" in the
>   middle   step? What exactly is the justification of the middle step in
>   cubical type theory? I can see how to prove `∀ i → f (loop i) = f (refl base i)`, but how does one "lift" that to `<i> f (loop i) = <i> f (refl base i)`?

I haven't received a response there so I'm going to try here, with concrete Agda code to back it.

I am trying to turn the above proof into Cubical Agda as follows. First, given `p`, the definition of `f` is straightforward:

```
  hyp : loop ≡ refl {x = base}

  p : x ≡ x

  f : S¹ → A
  f base = x
  f (loop i) = p i
```

We can prove *pointwise along `loop`* that `f (loop i) ≡ f (refl i)`:

```
  proofAt_ : ∀ i → f (loop i) ≡ f base
  proofAt i = cong (λ p → f (p i)) hyp
```

(to see why, here it is in more detail:

```
  proofAt_ : ∀ i → f (loop i) ≡ f base
  proofAt i = begin
    f (loop i)             ≡⟨ cong (λ p → f (p i)) hyp ⟩
    f (refl {x = base} i)  ≡⟨⟩
    f base                 ∎
```

)

but if I try to prove it for the whole thing:

```
  proof : p ≡ refl
  proof = begin
    (λ i → p i)             ≡⟨⟩
    (λ i → f (loop i))      ≡⟨ (λ i → proofAt i) ⟩
    (λ i → f base)          ≡⟨⟩
    (λ i → refl {x = x} i)  ∎
```

it fails, I would think because of the "interval extensionality" I am trying to use:

> Cannot instantiate the metavariable `_342` to solution `f (loop i) ≡ f base` since it contains the variable `i` which is not in scope of the
>   metavariable or irrelevant in the metavariable but relevant in the
>   solution
>
> when checking that the expression `proofAt i` has type `_A_342`

trying to eta-convert it to just `proofAt_` also fails, but for a different reason (and I think there is, in general, no eta conversion for paths):

```
  proof : p ≡ refl
  proof = begin
    (λ i → p i) ≡⟨⟩
    (λ i → f (loop i)) ≡⟨ proofAt_ ⟩
    (λ i → f base) ≡⟨⟩
    (λ i → refl {x = x} i) ∎
```

> `((i : I) → f (loop i) ≡ f base)` !=< `_344 ≡ _y_345` of type
>   `;Agda.Primitive.Setω`

So, what is the correct CTT transliteration of the above HoTT proof?

Comment: when you see things like f : Circle -> A, and f(loop) in the book, you should read them as shorthands for "cong f loop".

Comment: paths do have eta, but proofAt_ is not a path, it's a function from I to paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paths do have eta rules

https://github.com/Saizan/cubical-demo/blob/master/examples/Cubical/Examples/AIM_Demo/DemoPath.agda#L59

however the type path is not the same as the type of functions from the interval "I", so sometimes you need a lambda abstraction just to convert between the two types. (Lambda and application are ad-hoc overloaded between the two types).

`f loop` indeed does not typecheck, not in even in HoTT. However the book uses it as a shorthand for `ap f loop`, where `ap = cong` from the cubical library.

Also, your proof can be completed, but you need to use `proofAt_` correctly: the `i` dimension in `proof` is the one connecting `cong f loop` and `refl {x = f base}`, so you want to provide `i` as the second argument of `proofAt_`.

```
proof : p ≡ refl
proof = begin
  (λ i → p i)             ≡⟨⟩
  (λ i → f (loop i))      ≡⟨ (λ i j → proofAt j i) ⟩
  (λ i → f base)          ≡⟨⟩
  (λ i → refl {x = x} i)  ∎
```

Answer (score 3):

See Saizan's answer for a solution along the original lines. Alternatively, there is a simple solution:

```
proof : p ≡ refl
proof i j = f (hyp i j)
```

Or `proof = cong (cong f) hyp`. The key is that `hyp` is two-dimensional, and `f` acts on 0-dimensional elements, so `f` should be applied to the 0-dimensional components of `hyp`.

Comment: Functions ```(i : I) -> A``` are not just higher-order syntax, they have straightforward semantics in the cubical sets model and are occasionally quite convenient.

Comment: @Saizan thanks, I'm deferring to experts in this matter (removed my speculations).